# Determine all analytic $f$, wherefor $|f(z)| \leq C(|z|^ {3/2} + |z-1|^{-3/2})$ on $\mathbb{C}\backslash\{1\}$ for some $C>0$.

Tags: complex-analysis

Determine all analytic $f$, wherefor $|f(z)| \leq C(|z|^{3/2} + |z-1|^{-3/2})$ on $\mathbb{C}\backslash\{1\}$ for some $C>0$.

In the assignment f needs to have the following property as well:

$f(0)=f'(0)=0, f''(0) = 1$

i tried using the using an theorem of louiville, which states that:

if $f$ is holomorphic on $\mathbb{C}$ we say if $|f(z)|\leq M|z|^m$ for some $M<\infty$ and $m>0$, then $deg(f) \leq m$.

The main problem is that i have two terms on the right hand side, on top of that i don't see how to use the extra properties of f.

I got the feeling i need to use an other theorem, any hints or theorems that can help me in this case?

Kees

Comment: Do you mean $|z|^{3/2}$?

Comment: thanks, yes i mean that :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It follows from $|f(z)| \leq C(|z|^{3/2} + |z-1|^{3/2})$ that $f$
is bounded in a neighbourhood of $z=1$ and therefore has a
*removable singularity* at $z=1$. So $f$ can be extended to an
*entire* function.

For $|z|>1$ we have $|z-1| \le |z| + 1 < 2|z|$ and therefore
$$
|f(z)| \leq C(|z|^{3/2} + |z-1|^{3/2}) \le C(1+2^{3/2})|z|^{3/2} \le 5 C \, |z|^{3/2}
$$
It follows that $f$ is a polynomial of degree at most $1$.

---

*Update after question edit:*
It follows from $|f(z)| \leq C(|z|^{3/2} + |z-1|^{-3/2})$ that $f$
has a pole of order at most one at $z=1$:
$$
 f(z) = \frac{a}{z-1} + g(z)
$$
where $a \in \mathbb C$ and $g$ is an entire function.
Then for $|z|>2$ we have $  |z-1|  > 1$ and therefore
$$
 |g(z)| \le |f(z)| + |a| < C( |z|^{3/2} + 1) + |a| \le (2C + |a|)|z|^{3/2} \, .
$$
It follows that $g$ is a polynomial of degree at most one,
and therefore
$$
 f(z) = \frac{a}{z-1} + b + c z \, .
$$
The values for $a, b, c$ can now be determined by your initial
conditions $f(0)=f'(0)=0, f''(0) = 1$.

Comment: maximum 3/2 right, and i need to construct f such that f(0)=f'(0) =0 and f''(0) = 1

Comment: @KeesTil: Such a solution does not exist. It follows from the estimate that $f''$ is identically to zero – unless I made some error of course :)

Comment: f'' is 1 in zero...?

Comment: @KeesTil: Sorry, I don't understand you. If follows from the above estimate and Liouville's theorem that $f$ is a polynomial of degree at most one: $f(z) = a_0 + a_1 z$. In particular, $f''(0) = 0$. Therefore a solution with $f''(0) = 1$ does not exist.

Comment: i forgot the '-' in the |z-1| term, made a typo -______-

Comment: @KeesTil: See update :)

Comment: last question, how do you know the order of the pole is maximum 1. It can be 3/2 as well right...?

Comment: @KeesTil: There is no such thing as a pole of order 3/2. f has a pole of order n at a iff 1/f has a zero of order n at a.